# $multiply function not working in R studio

Tags: r, mongodb

this is my code chunk

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "total": {
        "$multiply": [
          "$items.quantity",
          "$items.price"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

This is what it outputs

[image]

This is a sample document

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is due to your `$group` stage. it works similar to SQL's `groupby` if you're more familiar.

What this means is that the `quantity` and `price` field are lost during that stage. you'll have to modify it a little to retain them.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve as you did not specify but here is a toy example of what I imagine you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$items.name",
      quantity: {
        $sum: "$items.quantity"
      },
      price: {
        $first: "$items.price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "total": {
        "$multiply": [
          "$quantity",
          "$price"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/agpPVg_x97g)